# Simplifier Tool for Windows

Tags: math-software

Is there any math formula reduction  tools?

for example convert:

> $\frac{a(a+1)}{2a}$

to:

> $\frac{a+1}{2}$

Comment: Actually, it should be $(a+1)/2$, not $a+1/2$, since $a+1/2$ means $a+(1/2)$.

Comment: Actually that's only true if you assume that $a\neq0$.

Comment: Another way of putting Michael's comment: parentheses are cheap. Use them when there is a potential source of ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica has [the command `FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullSimplify.html), for example. One can use it for free on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/); here it is in action [simplifying $\frac{a(a+1)}{2a}$ into $\frac{a+1}{2}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify%5Ba%28a%2B1%29%2F%282a%29%5D&t=crmtb01).

Comment: Is there any desktop software or plugin?

Comment: matlab can do this, by using sym method.

Comment: There are both mobile apps and widgets: http://products.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 3):

Two more ideas (free software for the desktop):

1. Maxima: a widespread free symbolic-math software; can even be configured to simplify wrt special trigonometric expressions (I use this if I have complicated expressions, derivatives and/or integrals)
2. (examples  like yours above can even be handled by Pari/GP; but is not specialized on symbolic expressions and can simplify polynomial/series expressions, and -but only to a very small extent- rational functions. Likely not what you want)

Comment: +1 for Maxima, let's add link: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/